# How to cunsume Java based Soap Web Service in javascript/ajax?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web-services, soap-client

I've to provide a .jsp page(index.jsp) along with my Web Service project for testing purpose.
Basically the .jsp page has a textarea, for reading a soap request as a string & on submitting it the soap response will come.

I tried it with "javax.xml.ws.Service & Dispatch" class, it's working fine.
But now I'm asked for a javascript/ajax based code.

Can anybody help me regarding this.

I'm giving a sample .wsdl file here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://zensar.com/greeting" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Greeting"
    xmlns:grtng="http://zensar.com/greeting/schema"
    targetNamespace="http://zensar.com/greeting">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://zensar.com/greeting">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://zensar.com/greeting/schema"
                schemaLocation="Greeting.xsd"></xsd:import>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GreetingRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="grtng:GreetingRequest" name="GreetingRequest" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GreetingResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="grtng:GreetingResponse" name="GreetingResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="GreetingPort">
        <wsdl:operation name="Greeting">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GreetingRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GreetingResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="Greeting" type="tns:GreetingPort">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Greeting">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://zensar.com/GreetingWS/Greeting" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="Greeting">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:Greeting" name="Greeting">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8085/Greeting/services" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>**
```

Comment: I'd consider writing a JAX-RS/JSON based service over the same business logic. This should be much less painful than trying to consume SOAP from Javascript

Comment: It's also possible that JAX-WS supports JSON+plain HTTP endpoints for "regular"/non-REST web services as well.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd say consuming the web service directly through javascript is a bit masochistic.

In my opinion it'd be much easier for the javascript to call a server side method (with whatever architecture that may be, c#, java, php etc) then do a CURL request and send the response back to the front end.

Writing out a soap endpoint by hand in javascript just seems pointless when you could use something like Axis2 at the server side to do the boiler plate heavy loading of the SOAP handshake.